# Appending a csv file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

So I am making a space invaders game in python, the game will take the score the player has achieved and will add it to a csv file. My code for the csv file is:

```
col = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, mobs)
if col:
    with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a", newline" ") as f:
        w = csv.writer(f, dilimiter = ",")
        for i in range(len(score)):
            w.writerow(name[i], score[i]])
    crashed = True
```

However, I get the error:

```
  File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Desktop\Computing Project\Galaxian.py", line 162
    with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a", newline" ") as f:
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am really stuck with this problem and I have no idea how to solve it. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is my code because I am probably going about this in a completely idiotic way:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys
import csv

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE names)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
ORANGE = (255, 255, 0)
YELLOW = (0, 255, 255)

DISPLAY_WIDTH = 720
DISPLAY_HEIGHT = 720  # sets res for the screen

FPS = 60

# --- classes --- (CamelCase names)

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images\\user1.gif").convert()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed_x = 0

    def update(self):
        self.speed_x = 0
        keystate = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keystate[pygame.K_LEFT]:
            self.speed_x = -10
        if keystate[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
            self.speed_x = 10
        self.rect.x += self.speed_x
        if self.rect.right > DISPLAY_WIDTH:
            self.rect.right = DISPLAY_WIDTH
        if self.rect.left < 0:
            self.rect.left = 0

    def shoot(self):
        bullet = Bullet(self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top)
        all_sprites.add(bullet)
        bullet_group.add(bullet)

class Mob(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.speed_y = random.randrange(5, 11)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images\\enemy1.gif").convert()
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (50, 50))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.speed_x = 0
        self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, DISPLAY_WIDTH - self.rect.width)
        self.rect.y = random.randrange(-500, -40)
        self.speedy = random.randrange(5, 11)

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speedy
        if self.rect.top > DISPLAY_HEIGHT + 10:
            self.rect.x = random.randrange(0, DISPLAY_WIDTH - self.rect.width)
            self.rect.y = random.randrange(-500, -40)


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images\\laser1.gif").convert()  # sets the laser to be the image laser1.gif
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, (15, 25))  # trasforms the size to fit the screen
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()  # sets hit box up, will fit around the image
        self.rect.bottom = y
        self.rect.centerx = x
        self.speed_y = -30

    def update(self):
        self.rect.y += self.speed_y
        if self.rect.bottom < 0:
            self.kill()
# --- functions --- (lower_case names)

# --- main --- (lower_case names)

score =0
name = raw_input("Enter your name: ")
# - init -

pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()

display = pygame.display.set_mode((DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))
display_rect = display.get_rect()

# - objects and groups -

all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()  # creates class that all sprites will be in
mobs = pygame.sprite.Group()  # creates class that all mobs will be stored in
bullet_group = pygame.sprite.Group()  # creates class that all bullets will be stored in
player = Player()  # assigns the player variable to the player class
player.rect.center = ((DISPLAY_WIDTH / 2), DISPLAY_HEIGHT / 1.2)  # sets the player to spawn at the bottom and in the middle of the screen
all_sprites.add(player)  # adds player to the all_sprites group

for z in range(12):  # spawns 13 enemies
    mob = Mob()
    mobs.add(mob)
    all_sprites.add(mob)

# - other -

pygame.mixer.music.load("audio\\soundtrack.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)  # sets music to play in an infinite loop
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.2)

# - mainloop -
crashed = False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not crashed:

    # - events -
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LCTRL:
                player.shoot()
        print(event)

    # - updates (without draws) -

    all_sprites.update()  # updates sprite positions without drawing them onto the screen

    # - draws (without updates) -

    background = pygame.image.load("images\\background.jpg")  # assigns the picture to a variable called background
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (DISPLAY_WIDTH, DISPLAY_HEIGHT))  # streches the picture to fit the screen

    display.blit(background, (0, 0))  # displays the background image

    all_sprites.draw(display)  # draws all sprites onto the screen

    font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 15)
    text = font.render("Score: " + str(score), True, BLACK)
    display.blit(text, (0, 0))

    pygame.display.update()  # updates display
    # - Checks for a hit -

    col = pygame.sprite.groupcollide(mobs, bullet_group, True, True)
    if col:  # if col = true then
        mob = Mob()  # spawns new mob
        mobs.add(mob)
        all_sprites.add(mob)
        score += 10

    # - checks for a collision -
    col = pygame.sprite.spritecollideany(player, mobs)
    if col:
        with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a", newline" ") as f:
            w = csv.writer(f, dilimiter = ",")
            for i in range(len(score)):
                w.writerow(name[i], score[i]])
        crashed = True

    # - FPS -

    clock.tick(FPS)  # built in function to make the program stay below specified frame per second

# - end -
pygame.quit()
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Try just this: `with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a") as f:`

Comment: or just make it  `newline=" " `

Comment: Just **look at the line in question**. There is an obvious missing character.

Comment: @jonrsharpe But what character would be missing? I tried taking out the 'newline = "" ' but I am still getting the same error

Comment: ...you didn't have `newline = ""` to start with.

Comment: Yes, I did, why would I change the code that I am asking for help with?

Comment: @Chirag I tried doing that and changing the variable name but the error stays the same, it tells me
File "C:\Users\Harry\Desktop\Desktop\Computing Project\Galaxian.py", line 162
    with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a") as f_Name
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a", newline" ") as f:`

Should be:

`with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a") as f:`

`delimiter` is misspelled as `dilimiter` but is unneeded anyway.

The `f.writerow` arguments are not quite what you want here.

Next time try [making a working reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that has all bits of code needed to work including import statements.

Actual working version:

```
import csv
name=['foo','bar']
score=[12345,54321]
with open("rec_Scores.csv", "a") as f:
    w = csv.writer(f)
    for i in range(len(score)):
        w.writerow([str(name[i]),str(score[i])])
```